# Alias to record all commands and std output to a file

Tags: linux, bash, output, stdout, record

I am looking to figure out a way to get my documentation done quicker for my project work. One thing that would help me would be to record my history and each commands output to a file. However, I don't want to have this on all the time and I would rather not have it as a toggle option for the risk of forgetting to turn it off and recording a load of junk that I will have to just go and delete later.

The idea I had was to create an alias, lets say 'verbatim', so that I could enter the command as so:

```
verbatim <command>
```

And then the alias would remove 'verbatim', take whatever  that was entered and prepend/append it with:

```
echo -n \[\$(date)\] >> output_file | echo "<command>" >> output_file | <command> | fee -a output_file | echo " " >> output_file
```

where the output will be:

```
<timestamp>
<command>
<outputOfTheCommand>
<newLine>
```

could also add comments by

```
verbatim #some comment to go in line
```

example:

```
verbatim #deploying the production stack upgrade 
verbatim <someDeployCommand>
```

This way by typing just one word extra per line I can record everything that happens as I am doing a deployment for example, which can be used to basically do all of my documentation for me since it is saved to a file in order, all I have to do is remove anything that is irrelevant in hindsight. And the fact that all the data is timestamped means it could also speed up RCA if something goes wrong.

Thanks in advance, any and all advice welcome

Answer (score 0):

I would just do my deployment as usual, and then add 
`head -n 20 ~/.bash_history`
and edit the 20 depending on the history size I want.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just use `script`, but you could do something like:

```
v() { { date; echo "$@"; "$@" | tee /dev/tty; echo; } >> ${OUTPUT-/tmp/output} 2>&1; }
```

or

```
v() { { date; echo "$@"; "$@"; echo; } 2>&1 | tee -a ${OUTPUT-/tmp/output}; }
```

(`verbatim` is too long, so I shortened it to `v`)

This won't handle comments at all; that would require writing a new parser, since the comment will never be seen by the function.  But you can always `echo "# some comment" >> $OUTPUT`